# Convert pkl file to json file

Tags: python, json, pickle, jsonpickle

I'm new on stack-overflow.

I'm trying to convert pkl file into json file using python. Below is my sample code

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd

# Load pickle file
input_file = open('file.pkl', 'rb')
new_dict = pickle.load(input_file)
input_file()

# Create a Pandas DataFrame
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)

# Copy DataFrame index as a column
data_frame['index'] = data_frame.index

# Move the new index column to the from of the DataFrame
index = data_frame['index']
data_frame.drop(labels=['index'], axis=1, inplace = True)
data_frame.insert(0, 'index', index)

# Convert to json values
json_data_frame = data_frame.to_json(orient='values', date_format='iso', date_unit='s')
with open('data.json', 'w') as js_file:
    js_file.write(json_data_frame)
```

When I run this code I got error that `TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable`. By following some same issues [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421209/typeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-is-not-callable-creating-text-file-error) and [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625150/io-textiowrapper-object-is-not-callable?rq=1), these issues suggested to use `write` method with `input_file()` at line 7 but still I'm getting this error `io.UnsupportedOperation: write` which is probably a writing method but I'm using it with reading and for reading I'm unable to fine any method. 
I also tried to read pickle file in following way

```
with open ('file.pkl', 'rb') as input_file:
    new_dict = pickle.load(input_file)
```

and I'm getting this error

```
DataFrame constructor not properly called!.
```

I need some kind suggestions that how I can solve this problem?
Any suggestions about other tools which can perform this task, will be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: What is the pickled object in `file.pkl`? And what was the purpose of this line `input_file()`? I think you were looking for `input_file.close()`.

Comment: For better understanding here is my pkl dictionary data.  {1:  {'pose': array([-3.101, 0.014, 0.022], dtype=float32), 'betas': array([0.073, -0.319, -0.114], dtype=float32)}}.  There are two main objects, pose data and betas data.

Comment: Can you please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257147/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-json-format) and check if it solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. I have solve my problem. The problem was due to serialization. JSON format is quite different and built-in json module can only handle primitives types that have a direct JSON equivalent (lists, dictionary, strings etc.) so I used JSONEncoder to solve this problem.

Comment: please answer your own quest. Otherwise this post will be found if someone searches for questions without answers.